# A rule that updates the same field of two different content types nodes (related by node title)

Tags: nodes, entities, rules

I'm trying to find the way to do this with a rule:

I have 2 different content types. Profile and Reminders.
One boolean field is shared between them.

Every time a new Profile node is created, the default value of the boolean field is on.

Note: When creating a new reminder node, the name of the Title field will be the same of the Profile node Title.
Every time a new reminder node is created, the default value of the boolean field is on.

So, we have... (example)

Node type: Profile
title: Somename
Boolean: Active

Node type: Reminder
title: Somename
Boolean: Active

What i want to do is a rule that behaves like this
When updating the value of the boolean field of the profile node "Somename",
then update the same boolean field of the reminder node type node

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but first, instead of linking them by giving them the same name, you should link them by using [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference). (You can still give them the same name, but we'll be just be using entity reference for the relationship purpose). Believe me, this is the better method. Once you do this, I or someone else will be happy to answer your Q.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I'll read about entity reference module. Sounds like it does the link between contents i need.

Comment: This [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_reference) does the trick